# Trim Command Not Working

Tags: excel, trim

Hello Every One,
                I am trying to trim some data in excel column but leading spaces are not removed and hence vlookup function is also not matching the data properly due to the leading spaces. Can anobody tell me how can I remove these leading and trailing spaces(may be)?

Comment: Check if there is an apostrophe (') before the text - use F2 on a cell where Trim isn't working.

Comment: data must be in a weird format, where is it coming from?

Comment: show a screenshot you can use "*"&A1&"*"

Answer (score 0):

@pnuts noted a possible solution so I just wanted to bump it and explain...the TRIM function only trims spaces, and it only trims the ones at the beginning and end of the cell text. I discovered the hard way that are a variety of non-printing characters beyond just spaces; CLEAN can get rid of these (hat tip: https://exceljet.net/formula/remove-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-text). For me when I had literally hundreds of thousands of rows with weird messy data of non-printing characters, the solution proposed by the link worked: use both TRIM and CLEAN nested inside each other.

Example:

```
    =TRIM(CLEAN(A1))
```

There's a lot of other trouble I ran into trying to make this work throughout the spreadsheet, but this actually got the result I needed as a first step.

Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW [`TRIM`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9) also removes extra spaces between words

Comment: Hey @Slai , no, TRIM doesn't remove spaces between characters, only leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: meaning that 2 or more spaces become 1

Comment: @Ruthie Kelly TRIM does replace two or more consecutive spaces between words with a single space